# Can I use laminate flooring if it got wet in storage?

Tags: flooring, water-damage, laminate-floor

I have ~850sf of Mohawk Revwood Premier that was in storage and we didn't reallize it was being leaked on. A little is dry, and definitely still useable. The ones that are wet are mostly just the edges, the tounge and groove basically, and there is next to no swelling on most edges. There are a few that are obviously unusable, but only on one end, the other is dry and perfect. I have a couple of questions, but here's more information first:

- This is meant to be a temporary floor while kids grow so we can put hardwood in later. Obviously we don't want it to look like complete shit but right now I have OSB subfloors, which will also be going away when we do hardwood, and if it's better looking than that I don't care if there's seams that are a little raised or sit kinda funny or really even if it's still waterproof, I just need a working, finished floor.
- Kitchen and dining room floors only
- We are doing this ourselves. We are trying to recover from a major flood that destroyed the first floor of our home. I don't want to buy another floor if I can make this one work until I'm done needing it. We're handy as hell but not professional by any means.
- If we can't save enough to do a whole room, we would at that point just do hardwood, because I am not paying that much for laminate twice.
- I have 3 untouched boxes. The rest are varying degrees of wet and will need to be dried.
- I currently have about nine boxes worth of planks drying on pallets in my back yard. Knee jerk reaction, made me question myself and come here to ask questions.

Now to my questions. Please be kind, I am learning, and panicking lol... I want to do things right but sometimes you have to roll with what you've got.

1. If I dry it out and it doesn't warp or swell beyond being able to install, should I even try? Will it hold up at all after being water damaged?
2. They have t&g on the ends of the boards, and some of them are wet but it's just the last eight inches of the board, can I cut them off and still use? I'm willing to use fasteners or adhesive to put them down if that's what it needs, the OSB subfloor will be going in the trash right along with them when they go.

I'm trying to determine whether the work of drying, cutting, and installing irregular Laminate is worth it, and I'm hoping someone will be able to help me.

Comment: Most laminate is only water resistant. Some is water proof.  The resistant type does not like soaking in water, but spill a bit and wipe up is okay.  Ends wet only can be cut off, but should match cut on the next piece/cut both together.  The tonque and groove is almost machined to size, eye balling difference not good enough, unless want to teach the kids new words.

Comment: The Mohawk Revwood Premier is waterproof if installed to Mohawk's specs.

Comment: I'm like minded in wanting to use a product even if it may be less than "out of the box " perfect.  However wood, especially laminate flooring does not react well to water.  Can you still use it as you described?  Probably if you are as handy as you tell us you are.  It will not be a perfect floor, but that's not what you are looking for.  I say go for it.  You will be able to tell if it will satisfy you after about 3 or 4 courses.

Comment: If it is water proof, then just getting wet should not bother it.  Just dry and put down.  At least you see if they stand up to their water proof statement.

Comment: Do you think I may need to use fasteners or adhesive? Wondering if cut boards will have too much movement where the ends don't lock together or if the tension from the side grooves will do enough work to keep them joined? I have brand new joists and subfloor, everything is near perfect level and but may pour leveler anyway to make the surface plumb, so adhesive would probably be better..but should I use it?

Comment: Crip- the installed floor is waterproof, but the individual laminate planks are not.

Comment: Will the cut ends need fasteners?   This is something that remains to be seen.  If I was putting the floor down I would use some polyurethane  caulk under the cut ends. It will glue the board down, but still allow the floor to have a little movement.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like I'll be drying a second round while I have some sunlight left!